# iOS - Unable to call action from dynamically created button in UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uitableview

i have created two button programmatically in UITableView
 i.e Edit Delete

when we click the cell these buttons are displayed but when i try to click in **edit or delete** button it doesn't calls the appropriate method i.e edit or deleteBtn.
This is my code.

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier=@"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if(cell==nil){
        cell=[[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier]autorelease];
    }

    NSString *cellValue=[firstName objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text=cellValue;


    edit=[[UIButton alloc]init];
    [edit setTitle:@"Edit" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [edit setFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 20)];
    [edit setTag:1];
    [edit addTarget:self action:@selector(edit) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    delete=[[UIButton alloc]init];
    [delete setTitle:@"Delete" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [delete setFrame:CGRectMake(150, 100, 100, 20)];
    [delete setTag:2];
    [delete addTarget:self action:@selector(deleteBtn) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [cell.contentView addSubview:delete];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:edit];

    return cell;

}
```

my edit and delete function are very simple

```
-(void)edit{

NSLog("%@",selectedValue);
}

-(void)deleteBtn{

NSLog("%@",selectedValue);
}
```

i have checked this function applying breakpoint but it is not called.

this is how my **selectedValue** comes

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
selectedValue=[firstName objectAtInder:indexPath.row];
}
```

Thanks, in advance,
Arun.

Comment: post your edit and deleteBtn methods.

Comment: What do the edit and delete methods look like?

Comment: will you paste code of edit or deleteBtn?

Comment: i created this function to call webservices for delete or edit the selected record

Comment: did you put "UITableViewDatasourceDelegate" and "UITableViewDelegate"? in .h file

Comment: yes i added "UITableViewDatasourceDelegate" and "UITableViewDelegate"

Comment: Check my answer, I've set tag as indexPath.row value, so it'll give you name which you had selected. -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15470502/ios-unable-to-call-action-from-dynamically-created-button-in-uitableviewcell/15470836#15470836

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think,the problem is with `UIButton` frame's.
in your code both button's `origin.y` is 100.0,so it went beyond the cell's bound (Default height is 44.0).

Change your Both `UIButton` frame like this,and it is worked for me.

```
UIButton *  edit =[[UIButton alloc]init];
[edit setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
[edit setTitle:@"Edit" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
**[edit setFrame:CGRectMake(100,5.0,100, 30)];**
[edit setTag:1];
[edit addTarget:self action:@selector(edit) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

UIButton*  delete=[[UIButton alloc]init];
[delete setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
[delete setTitle:@"Delete" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
**[delete setFrame:CGRectMake(200,5.0,100,30)];**
[delete setTag:2];
[delete addTarget:self action:@selector(deleteBtn) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

[cell.contentView addSubview:delete];
[cell.contentView addSubview:edit];
```

Comment: it worked ,but edit button is displayed in all cell automatically,i want it to display when the cell is selected,the delete button appears when i select any row.

Comment: you can add delete button in - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {} in this method.

Answer (score 2):

please your code like below

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
static NSString *CellIdentifier=@"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if(cell==nil){
    cell=[[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier]autorelease];
}

NSString *cellValue=[firstName objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.text=cellValue;


edit=[[UIButton alloc]init];
[edit setTitle:@"Edit" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[edit setFrame:CGRectMake(100, 5, 100, 20)];
[edit setTag:indexPath.row];
[edit addTarget:self action:@selector(edit:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[cell addSubview:edit];   

delete=[[UIButton alloc]init];
[delete setTitle:@"Delete" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[delete setFrame:CGRectMake(210, 5, 100, 20)];
[delete setTag:indexPath.row];
[delete addTarget:self action:@selector(deleteBtn:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[cell addSubview:delete];

return cell;
```

}

use methods like below

```
-(IBAction)edit:(id)sender
{
    int tag = [sender tag];
    NSString *str = [firstName objectAtIndex:tag];
    NSLog("%@",str);
 }

 -(IBAction)deleteBtn:(id)sender
 {
    int tag = [sender tag];
    NSString *str = [firstName objectAtIndex:tag];
    NSLog("%@",str);
 }
```

Comment: using like you can get which object is called

Answer (score 1):

Your buttons are being added over and over to the cell because they're being created every time you call CFRAIP.  Move them into the `cell == nil` block:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier=@"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if(cell==nil){
        cell=[[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier]autorelease];
        edit=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];;
        [edit setTitle:@"Edit" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [edit setFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 20)];
        [edit setTag:1];
        [edit addTarget:self action:@selector(edit) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

        delete=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];;
        [delete setTitle:@"Delete" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [delete setFrame:CGRectMake(150, 100, 100, 20)];
        [delete setTag:2];
        [delete addTarget:self action:@selector(deleteBtn) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

        [cell.contentView addSubview:delete];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:edit];
    }

    NSString *cellValue=[firstName objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text=cellValue;
    return cell;

}
```

Comment: I agree with @mohan, change your button declaration.  I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the `setFrame`

The height of the table cell is less than the co-ordinates you have set for the buttons.
Change the code to

```
[edit setFrame:CGRectMake(100, 5, 100, 20)];
```

and this will work.

**OR**

just increase the `height` of the table rows, which by default is `44`, using

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use this one ....and do same thing for delete button ..........

```
if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

        // -------------------- Add button to cell --------------
        edit = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 20)];

        [edit setTitle:@"Edit" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [edit setTag:1];
        [edit addTarget:self action:@selector(edit)   forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];        

        [cell.contentView addSubview:edit];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Pls change the button names , as Edit and delete are already defined keywords in Objective C

Answer (score 0):

I can you try to custom cell and can you add buttons in custom cell view and implement below codes.

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    cell = [self.tbl dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {


        //****cell recent deal buy button click goes to login or check out pageview 
        //[cell.btn setTag:indexPath.row];
        //[cell.btn addTarget:self action:@selector(buybutton_checkout:)
       //   forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
       // cell.btn.hidden=NO;


        NSArray* views = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"icel" owner:nil options:nil];

        for (UIView *view in views)
        {
            if([view isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]])
            {

                cell = (icel*)view;

            }

        }
    }

   //tbl.layer.cornerRadius = 3.9;
    //[tbl setClipsToBounds:YES];


    [cell.activity startAnimating]; 

    [cell.btn setTitle:_BUYNOW_BTN forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [cell.btn setTag:indexPath.row];
    [cell.btn addTarget:self action:@selector(Buy_btnlck:)
                forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
        //cell.btn.hidden=NO;
    cell.title_lbl.text=[[_today_similardeal_title_ary objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]capitalizedString];


        index_tbl=indexPath.row;
    return cell;
    }
}
-(IBAction)Buy_btnlck:(UIButton *)button
{
NSInteger intvalue=[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",(long int)[button tag]]intValue];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify your code as like this....

Replace the below two lines...

```
edit=[[UIButton alloc] init];
delete=[[UIButton alloc] init];
```

as like this...

```
UIButton *edit = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];

UIButton *delete=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `[UIButton alloc] init]`. Use instead this

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[button addTarget:self 
           action:@selector(edit:)
 forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
[button setTitle:@"Edit" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
 button.frame = CGRectMake(80.0, 21.0, 40.0, 40.0);
[view addSubview:button];
```

Where view is the view where you are adding your button as a subview. you can also set Button frame according to your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Try this::

Table Method

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   // Configure the cell.
   UITableViewCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

   if(cell==nil){
      cell= [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle: UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier: CellIdentifier] autorelease];

      NSString *cellValue=[firstName objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
      cell.textLabel.text=cellValue;

      UIButton *btnEdit=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
      [btnEdit setTitle:@"Edit" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
      [btnEdit setFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 20)];
      [btnEdit setTag:indexPath.row];
      [btnEdit addTarget:self action:@selector(clickEdit:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

      [cell.contentView addSubview:btnEdit];


      UIButton *btnDelete=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
      [btnDelete setTitle:@"Delete" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
      [btnDelete setFrame:CGRectMake(150, 100, 100, 20)];
      [btnDelete setTag:indexPath.row];
      [btnDelete addTarget:self action:@selector(clickDelete:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

      [cell.contentView addSubview:btnDelete];
   }
   return cell;
}
```

Then, Button Action Methods

```
-(IBAction)clickEdit:(id)sender
{
   NSString *str = [firstName objectAtIndex:[sender tag]];
   NSLog("Name :: %@",str);
}

-(IBAction)clickDelete:(id)sender
{
   NSString *str = [firstName objectAtIndex:[sender tag]];
   NSLog("Name :: %@",str);
}
```

Hopefully, it'll help you.

Thanks.